# Where can I see the third-party app scheduled post status on Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

- Facebook wants to see scheduled posts by third-party apps like Buffer, Hootsuite, etc.
- On Facebook, there are 3 types of post availability. Profile, Page & Group.
- Used API for scheduling posts from our app.
- In the Facebook help desk, they provide steps to see Schedule posts, but there is a change in Facebook UI, and not found. (https://www.facebook.com/help/android-app/278940075619410)
- Is that any way to check the status of scheduled posts on Facebook?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not programming-related.

Comment: Hi, @CBroe I want to know the API related to this, so it is basically related to the programming question. Thank you!